# How to map Java Bean property to another name for output?

Tags: java, javabeans

I have several properties in a Java Bean that does not look pretty. E.g. max_speed. There are too many properties for me to want to manually write them up in my HTML-file so they look pretty.

Current output: max_speed, min_speed

Wanted output: Max Speed, Min Speed

Question: How do I map "max_speed", "min_speed" and 20 other properties to "Max Speed", "Min Speed" etc., for pretty output print? Is this doable without having to write them up manually every time I want to add them to a web page?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you have many properties for speed and you want a easy way to access those? Why don't you have a Class Speed and then you can have the attributes for MaxSpeed, MinSpeed, etc...

Comment: No, I want to print the properties, both the name, and their respective values. But when I print the property "max_speed", it does not look good, I would rather want "Max Speed" to be printed. I want this automated, as I don't want to write the manual pretty name for each property each time I want it printed to a web page.

Comment: Ok. So how about HashMap<String, String>. If the object value matches any key, just extract the value of that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these functions below;

**To Set the Display Name**

```
    public void setDisplayName(String givenProperty){

    String displayName = null;

    // Perform Some Operation to generate you display Name
    // String [] tokens = givenProperty.split("_");
    // displayName = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1];

    objectOfHashMap.put(givenProperty,displayName);

 }
```

**To get the DisplayName:**

```
   public String getDisplayName(HashMap<String, String> givenHashMap, String givenProperty){

       String outputString = null;

       for(Map.Entry<String, String> pairs1 : givenHashMap.entrySet()){
           if(givenProperty.equals((String)pairs1.getKey())){
                outputString = pairs1.getValue();
            }
        }

       return outputString;
    }
```

Let me know, if you have any questions.

Comment: To see what I ended up using, see my own answer below. It was derived from your setDisplayName-method, so I'll mark your answer as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What if you write a method, that expects a field name (property name) and returns a nicely formatted output?

For example:

```
public String formatProperty(String propertyName, String userFriendlyLabel) {
    Field someField = this.getClass().getField(propertyName);

    Object value = null;
    if(someField != null) {
       value = someField.get(this);
    }

    return userFriendlyLabel + ": " + value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code shown below will work for your specific use case:
It return formatted names for all methods and properties defined in a specific class if that class contains the property with "_" in it.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ReplaceMethodNames {

/**
 * @param args
 */
String max_speed;
String min_speed;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Provide the class Name as parameter you may want to format
    List<String> formattedNames =getFormattedProperties(ReplaceMethodNames.class); 
    System.out.println(formattedNames);
}

public static List<String> getFormattedNames(Class clazz){
    List<String> formattedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
    for(Method method:methods){
        String methodName = method.getName();
        StringBuilder newMethodName = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<methodName.length();i++){
            if(methodName.charAt(i)=='_') {
                newMethodName.append(' ');
                newMethodName.append(Character.toUpperCase(methodName.charAt(i+1)));
                i++;
            }else if(i==0){
                newMethodName.append(Character.toUpperCase(methodName.charAt(i)));
            }else {
                newMethodName.append(methodName.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        if(methodName.contains("_")){
            formattedNames.add(newMethodName.toString());
        }

    }
    return formattedNames;
}

public static List<String> getFormattedProperties(Class clazz){
    List<String> formattedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field:fields){
        String methodName = field.getName();
        StringBuilder newMethodName = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<methodName.length();i++){
            if(methodName.charAt(i)=='_') {
                newMethodName.append(' ');
                newMethodName.append(Character.toUpperCase(methodName.charAt(i+1)));
                i++;
            }else if(i==0){
                newMethodName.append(Character.toUpperCase(methodName.charAt(i)));
            }else {
                newMethodName.append(methodName.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        if(methodName.contains("_")){
            formattedNames.add(newMethodName.toString());
        }

    }
    return formattedNames;
}
public static void test_methodA(){}
public static void test_methodB(){}
public static void test_methodC(){}
public static void test_methodD(){}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this method for prettyfying(if that is allowed as a word) my properties, and adding some if else sentences for the special cases. Couldn't use switch case because Java 1.6 does not support switching on String, apparently. Notice the [WordUtils-package](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) from commons. NB: Notice that this only works for my special case, where all property-names are divided by underscores.

```
public String niceDisplayName(String property) {
    String[] tokens = property.split("_");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++) {
        tokens[i] = WordUtils.capitalize(tokens[i]);
        sb.append(tokens[i]);
        if((i+1) < tokens.length) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```